# Homology groups and embeddings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm working on the following problem:

Let $A$ be the image of an embedding $g: S^{1} \times D^{2} \rightarrow S^{3}$ . If $Y= S^{3} - $Int$(A)$
be the complement of its interior. Compute the homology groups $H_{*}(Y; \mathbb{Z}$) and $H_{*}(Y, \partial Y ; \mathbb{Z} $).

Since I'm a beginner in homology theory I have only learned to compute homology groups for very simple examples. Can someone help me go through this problem?

Comment: You say $Y=S^3-$Int$(V)$, but don't tell us what $V$ is, typo?

Comment: @albert Yes, that was a mistake. I meant to write $A$.

Answer (score 3):

For the first one, use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for homology, the relevant piece of which is

$$H_2(S^3) \longrightarrow H_1(T^2) \longrightarrow H_1(A) \oplus H_1(Y) \longrightarrow H_1(S^3).$$ The first and the last groups are trivial, and $H_1(T^2) \simeq \mathbb{Z}^2,$ so $H_1(Y) \simeq \mathbb{Z}.$

Your second question can be done similarly, but I leave it to you.

Comment: Maybe it is me who doesn't see it, but are you suggesting that $A\cap Y=Y$ is the $2$-torus?

Comment: @DavideTrono That is precisely what I am suggesting.

Comment: I see, but I don't understand why, at least I can't see it from a CW-complexes perspective.

Comment: @DavideTrono Well, $S^1 \times D$ is a solid torus. Its boundary is a torus.